# Difference between "sämtlich" and "alle"

Tags: meaning, difference, meaning-in-context

I wrote: Es soll gewährleistet werden, dass *sämtliche* Dokumente [...] zur Verfügung stehen.

*Sämtliche* was corrected to *alle*. What is the difference in meaning?

Comment: Who corrected that? In what context / for whom is the text?

Comment: Not all changes are corrections. (Not every change is a correction.)

Comment: @mtwde The text was corrected/changed by a native speaker correcting and commenting the text. The text is in the context of a process description. I wanted to write that all documents [that meet some criteria] should be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both words mean almost the same thing. However, "sämtlich" emphasizes that everything is clearly meant.

[Duden says](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/saemtlich)

> nachdrücklich für all (emphatically for all)

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/s%C3%A4mtlich)

> ausnahmslos alle (without exception all)

Why was it changed when you really meant "each and every document"? Probably because the difference is marginal and "sämtliche" could be seen as sublime language. Or he/she did not know better ^^. Both words are fine.

Comment: While I don't think the words are interchangeable, I'm not convinced the difference is that simple. For example (from the subtitles to "Mad Men" via DWDS) *In einem Jahr haben wir 81% sämtlicher Regenmäntel in den USA verkauft.* I don't think it works to translate this as "In one year we sold 81% of every one of the raincoats in the US."

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the difference is oversimplified language. The meaning is the [same](https://www.dwds.de/wb/s%C3%A4mtlich). Or maybe someone likes to "correct" your texts.

Comment: I agree that the basic meaning is the same, but the connotations are different: "Sämtliche Dokumente" to me has a stronger sense of "every last document, and don't you leave out a single one" than a more general "alle Dokumente".

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck And what makes you think you could leave out one or another document, when it says *alle*?

Comment: It just feels to me that the consequences (and probably the repercussions) would be more severe, more of an implied "or else". "Sämtliche Dokumente" could be out of a court order, "Dem Beklagten wird aufgegeben, dem Kläger sämtliche Dokumente zugänglich zu machen". On the other hand, "alle Dokumente" feels more general, more permissible to "bring' mal alle Dokumente, die Du so findest" than "sämtliche" would be. But, as I said, this doesn't change the basic meaning.